# How to set Jenkins Build to be always successful irrespective of SonarQube / Runner Analysis Result or Availability?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, exit-code, sonar-runner

Is there a way to set Jenkins build ignore SonarQube Analysis results (*Failure / Success*). This would be for the scenarios like SonarQube Upgrade / Unavailability, Ignore the Results for initial development phases.

For Windows slave, we can edit the `Error Code / Exit Code to '0'`  in Sonar-runner.bat file. How can we do that for a Linux Based slave ? Or is there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

For Linux, running a bash shell (arguably the de facto standard these days except in the embedded space), I use bash's ability to have more than one command on a line.

For instance, let's say `doit` may return 0 (passing) or !0 (failing), but I want Jenkins to always evaluate it as passing.

```
doit || true
```

Let's break that down.  `doit` is pretty obvious, it's the command I want run.  `true` is a little obscure, but it means to return a passing (0) value.  The magic is in the `||`.  It tells bash to run the first command (left side), and if the first command passes (returns 0) then stop; else it will run the second command and return the result of that.  Since the second command is `true`, the result of the line is always passing!